# I need to access all of the [Location][LocationCategory] in a list of dictionaries. There are 421 dictionaries in the list. Keep getting error

Tags: python

My list of dictionaries is 'atm_data' My current code is:

```
def atms_location_type(atms_data):
    atms_amount={'BranchExternal':0,'BranchInternal':0,'Other':0,'BranchLobby':0}
    for i in atms_data:
        if [i]['Location']['LocationCategory']=='BranchExternal':
            atms_amount['BranchExternal']+=1
        elif [i]['Location']['LocationCategory']=='BranchInternal':
            atms_amount['BranchInternal']+=1
        elif [i]['Location']['LocationCategory']=='BranchLobby':
            atms_amount['BranchLobby']+=1
        elif [i]['Location']['LocationCategory']=='Other':
            atms_amount['Other']+=1
            
    return (atms_amount)

atms_location_type(atms_data)
atms_amount_clear=atms_location_type(atms_data)
```

Comment: Can you post the error? Also what does your dictionary atm_data look like?

Comment: i fixed it! thank you though

Answer (score 1):

Should replace `[i]` with `i`, here one short code for you.

```py
def atms_location_type(atms_data):

    atms_amount={
        'BranchExternal':0,
        'BranchInternal':0,
        'BranchLobby':0,
        'Other':0,
    }

    for item in atms_data:
        tag = item['Location']['LocationCategory']
        if tag not in ['BranchExternal', 'BranchInternal', 'BranchLobby']:
            tag = 'Other'
        atms_amount[tag] += 1

    return atms_amount
```